# WPF app: Is it better to save images on DB or file system?

Tags: wpf, sqlite, sql-server-ce, blob

I have to build a WPF single user application that needs to handle images (about 200-500 kb.) for every record (>10000 records).

Do i better use a blob field in the DB or is it better to save imgs in the file system?

I'm trying to understand whether using Sqlite or SqlCE for database engine, but i've read about limitations and performance problems for both engines, so i think to save images in the file system even if it would be nicer to backup only the DB file to save everything. Is it a good choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all images in blob fields, every backup requires backing up the entire database file. With images in the file system, you could do incremental backups.

Depending on what you need to do with the images, it's likely that you have to export some images into files anyway.